# Is 你今天早上怎麼樣? or 你這個早上怎麼樣? okay for asking "How are you this morning?" and

Tags: word-choice, usage, word

Is "Ni jin tian zao shang zen me yang?（你今天早上怎麼樣？）" ok?

Can we also say, "Ni zhe ge zao shang zen me yang? （你這個早上怎麼樣？）" because we do say, "Ni zhe ge xing qi zen me yang? （你這個星期怎麼樣？）" for how are you this week..

Answer (score 2):

没有这个问法，一般工作环境会问“早上好”，不会问“你早上怎么样？”

Chinese people do not say it like this; they always say 早上好 (zǎoshang hǎo) = "morning" or 你早上怎么样？(Nǐ zǎoshang zěnme yàng?) = "good morning".

Answer (score 1):

"ni jin tian zao shang zen me yang" is ok, but not authentic. You can remove the subject, and try to say "zao shang hao ma", which is more casual for everyday conversation.

Comment: And what about zhe ge ? Is that acceptable too?

Comment: Do people actually say "zao shang hao ma" [早上好吗](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E2%80%9C%E6%97%A9%E4%B8%8A%E5%A5%BD%E5%90%97%E2%80%9C)?

Answer (score 1):

你会问“早上好吗”。 just say what’s under quotes as it’s more normal to see. Your translation is ok, just you wouldn’t hear a person say that normally.

Comment: Thanks... the one with zhe ge is ok too? Grammatically I mean, though I understand natives speak differently..

Answer (score 1):

As @李继鹏 pointed out, if you want to fit in Chinese culture, you'd say good morning rather than asking how are you. Chinese people never say how are you (in Chinese). It's just a culture thing.

I noticed you are learning Traditional Chinese. If you want to say good morning, 早上好 works in mainland China, in Taiwan we say 早安, or simply 早. Of course we understand 早上好, but 早安 is much more common.

If you really want to say those sentences, all of your translation is fine. People normally won't ask that. Asking 你今天（這個）早上怎麼樣？ feels like that you have a special event this morning, e.g. an exam, and you're asking about his/her performance, or that he/she was sick yesterday and you're asking if he/she feels better this morning.